# Joomla - Convenient Template Upgrades

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I recently migrated a website from Jekyll to Joomla (currently 3.9). Therefore I made an own Joomla Template. It is already in production, but of course it gets regular updates. I use a quite standard development/release approach, versioning like 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1 and so on. These numbers are always up to date in `templateDetails.xml`. Nothing special so far. But this has some very inconvenient issues:

- Every time I upgrade the template I have to set a different template/style as default, uninstall the old version, upload and install the current version and set its style as new default. **Is there really no better way for upgrading a template, especially if it has an higher version?**
- For each update all my configurations of the style get lost. I already put the defaults accordingly in the `templateDetails.xml`, so I don't have to do this on every upgrade. But I can imagine this may cause problems when I change the configuration in the back end without updating the template. This would result in potential configuration loss after an upgrade. **Can I keep any style configuration when upgrading?**
- Third, I'm thinking of using different styles for different pages on my website. These would also get lost when upgrading, so I'd have to redefine them regularly. I also would have to reconfigure all pages using these styles to use them again. **Is there a way to define several styles in `templateDetails.xml`, so they are *stored in my zip file***?

Edit: As Irfan asked for, here is my current templateDetails.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.8" type="template">
    <name>####</name>
    <creationDate>2018-11-03</creationDate>
    <author>####</author>
    <authorEmail>####@####.de</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>https://###.##.##</authorUrl>
    <copyright>SV FOO BAR e.V.</copyright>
    <license>TBA</license>
    <version>0.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Joomla-Template fuer die Vereinshomepage des SV FOO BAR e.V.</description>
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
        <filename>template_preview.png</filename>
        <filename>template_thumbnail.png</filename>
        <filename>main.css</filename>
        <filename>favicon.ico</filename>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>html</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
        <folder>js</folder>
    </files>
    <positions>
        <position>breadcrumb</position>
        <position>left</position>
        <position>right</position>
        <position>footer</position>
    </positions>
    <languages folder="language">
        <language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.tpl_svFOOBAR.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="advanced">
                <field
                    name="sitedescription"
                    type="text"
                    label="JGLOBAL_DESCRIPTION"
                    description="JGLOBAL_SUBHEADING_DESC"
                    default="This is my slogan"
                    filter="string" />
                <field
                    name="copyright-from"
                    type="number"
                    default="2005"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COPYRIGHT_FROM"
                    description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COPYRIGHT_FROM"
                    step="1"
                    required="true" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset name="cookieconsent">
                <field
                    type="spacer"
                    name="cookieconsent_separator_general"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_SEPARATOR_general" />
                <field
                    name="cookieconsent_activate"
                    type="checkbox"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_ACTIVATE"
                    description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_ACTIVATE"
                    checked="1"
                    value="1" />
                <field
                        name="cookieconsent_position"
                        type="list"
                        default="top"
                        required="true"
                        label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_POSITION"
                        description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_POSITION">
                          <option value="top">TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_POSITION_BANNER_TOP</option>
                            <option value="top-pushdown">TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_POSITION_BANNER_TOP_PUSHDOWN</option>
                            <option value="bottom">TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_POSITION_BANNER_BOTTOM</option>
                          <option value="bottom-left">TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_POSITION_FLOATING_LEFT</option>
                            <option value="bottom-right">TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_POSITION_FLOATING_RIGHT</option>
                    </field>

                <field
                    type="spacer"
                    name="cookieconsent_separator_colors"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_SEPARATOR_COLORS" />
                <field
                        name="cookieconsent_color_banner"
                        required="true"
                        type="color"
                        default="#efefef"
                        label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BANNER"
                        description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BANNER" />
                <field
                        name="cookieconsent_color_button"
                        required="true"
                        type="color"
                        default="#8ec760"
                        label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BUTTON"
                        description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BUTTON" />
                <field
                        name="cookieconsent_color_banner_text"
                        required="true"
                        type="color"
                        default="#404040"
                        label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BANNER_TEXT"
                        description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BANNER_TEXT" />
                <field
                        name="cookieconsent_color_button_text"
                        required="true"
                        type="color"
                        default="#ffffff"
                        label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BUTTON_TEXT"
                        description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_COLOR_BUTTON_TEXT" />

                <field
                    type="spacer"
                    name="cookieconsent_separator_texts"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_SEPARATOR_TEXTS" />
                <field
                    name="cookieconsent_learnmore_text"
                    type="text"
                    default="Mehr erfahren"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_LEARNMORE_TEXT"
                    description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_LEARNMORE_TEXT"
                    filter="string" />
                <field
                    name="cookieconsent_learnmore_link"
                    type="url"
                    default="impressum-datenschutz"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_LEARNMORE_LINK"
                    description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_LEARNMORE_LINK" />
             <field
                    name="cookieconsent_message"
                    type="textarea"
                    default="Um die Funktionalität und den Inhalt der Website zu optimieren, verwenden wir Cookies. Durch die Nutzung unserer Website stimmst du der Verwendung von Cookies zu."
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_MESSAGE"
                    description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_MESSAGE"
                    rows="10"
                    cols="5" />
                <field
                    name="cookieconsent_dismiss_button"
                    type="text"
                    default="Verstanden"
                    label="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_LABEL_COOKIECONSENT_DISMISS_BUTTON"
                    description="TPL_SVFOOBAR_FIELDS_DESCRIPTION_COOKIECONSENT_DISMISS_BUTTON" />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Comment: Add templateDetails.xml code in your post as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the extension tag to include a method of upgrade:

```
<extension version="3.8" type="template" method="upgrade" client="site">
```

Comment: I did not check, if this satifies all the issues i mentioned, but with this I can update my template without uninstalling it. Thank you so much, this is it!